# Assign role based on purchased products

Tags: commerce, redirection

I'm using the Drupal Commerce, Checkout redirect and Auto assign role modules.

When a checkout is completed by an anonymous user on a Drupal Commerce website a Drupal account will be created.

If there is only one product everything is ok, but what happen when there are many products?

How can I make it so that:

- If a user buys "Product 1" I will be auto-assing a role "Role 1"
- If a user buys "Product 2" I will be auto-assing a role "Role 2"

Could anyone solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar: user purchased an item (points) and depending on the purchased product a value (points) should be added to the user profile. The rule below is ready to accept (loop through) multiple products/lineItems. In my case I only need the first one:

```
 "value" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0:line-item-id" ],
        "limit" : "1"
```

First I fetch the purchased products (line items) by property (line_item_id). The result is an array (list of purchased products).

Next you need to loop through this array/list and add the desired action to the individual/current purchased product. If you need a condition (product 1 -> role 1) you can use conditional rules. It is an awesome rules addon that lets you insert IF conditions within loops (so you dont have to create a component that checks the product).

```
{ "rules_purchasing_points" : {
"LABEL" : "PURCHASE Points",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_payment" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "entity_query" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "commerce_line_item",
        "property" : "line_item_id",
        "value" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-line-items:0:line-item-id" ],
        "limit" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "entity-fetched" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "data_convert" : {
            "USING" : { "type" : "decimal", "value" : [ "list-item:line-item-label" ] },
            "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "conversion_result" : "Conversion result" } }
          }
        },
        { "component_rules_set_points" : {
            "recipient" : [ "site:current-user" ],
            "sender" : "1",
            "points" : [ "conversion-result" ]
          }
        },
```